# Is there a way to hide my NodeJs source code on customer server?

Tags: node.js

I've developed a web-based NodeJS APIs for my customer and it gonna be hosted on their private server. However, I intended to reuse most part the code for other customer in the future. How can I hide my code on their server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know about two options.

1. You can minify and obfuscate your sourcecode same as you do with FE JS. Using webpack and minifiers and other tools. Notice this can also help with some performance and cold starts if lambdas are used and also make your code smaller making it faster to upload (faster ci/cd). If you use docker, I recommend docker multistage build.
2. Or second you can precompile your code, for example with nexe https://github.com/nexe/nexe, but there are more tools for that. But then you dont end up with nodejs code but compiled binary and than it depends how services works on customers server meaning if you are allowed to execute binaries or you are supposed to provide `index.js` file.

Comment: Thank for your advice, will mark this as accepted answer as of now.